# Publish which depends on user state

Tags: meteor

I have publish method that depends on user state:

```
Meteor.publish('myGroup', function () {
  if (this.userId != null) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    return Group.find(user.profile.groupId);
  } else {
    return [];
 }
});
```

When user state changes (user.profile.groupId), I don't get new data. I can fix it by refreshing the browser.

I was trying to fix that, by making subscription reactive:

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  var user = Meteor.user(); // depend on user
  if (user != null) {
    Meteor.subscribe('myGroup');
  }
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you see that your autorun function is actually running on user change?

Comment: Yes, the autorun run on user change. Actually after testing, this code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Passing unused parameters seems to be the best workaround:

```
Meteor.subscribe("myGroup", user.profile.groupId);
```

Comment: It is unsecure because client decide the group id. It is not recomended.

Comment: Server doesn't use this argument at all. Though I agree you need to be careful with allow/deny rules on user.profile.